# pandas read_excel returns one column ending with .1

Tags: pandas

**Code**

```
df=pd.read_excel(path, usecols=range(32,89), skiprows=9)
for col in df.columns:
    print(col)
```

**Output:**

```
col1
col2
col3
col4
col5.1
.
.
.
col57
```

If you see the output, only the `col5 is suffix with .1`

**Update:**

I found the issue, there is another col5 in the xlsx, but that is in the range 10, which i'm not reading at all.. why even if i read from range 32, its considering the same column is exist?

Comment: The parsers module is rather complicated, but it's probably something to do with [read()](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.24.2/pandas/io/parsers.py#L1993-L2007). You can see that `_maybe_dedup_names` is called before filtering with `use_cols`

Comment: @ALollz: is it a bug or this is expected behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may not be reading column number 10 but clearly `pd.read_excel` is before it passes the result to you.  You can change the behavior by using the following as described in the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html)

```
pd.read_excel(
    path, 
    usecols=range(32,89), 
    skiprows=9, 
    mangle_dupe_cols=False
)
```

Comment: is the attribute available only in the recent version of pandas?